# Time capsule: Error deleting partial image

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I have two machines backing up to a Time Capsule. On the disk there a faulty disk image which was marked as *purgeable* but cannot be deleted:

```
2013-08-15 6:00:16.847 PM com.apple.backupd[13566]: Found 1 partially deleted backup image.
2013-08-15 6:00:26.918 PM com.apple.backupd[13566]: Failed to remove file://localhost/Volumes/Data/NAME .purgeable/, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "“NAME .purgeable” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo=0x7f8292c029d0 {NSFilePath=/Volumes/Data/NAME .purgeable, NSUserStringVariant=(
Remove ), NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8292c02920 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument"}
2013-08-15 6:00:26.927 PM com.apple.backupd[13566]: Error deleting partial image /Volumes/Data/NAME .purgeable: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "“NAME .purgeable” couldn’t be removed." UserInfo=0x7f8292c029d0 {NSFilePath=/Volumes/Data/NAME .purgeable, NSUserStringVariant=( Remove ), NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8292c02920 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Invalid argument"}
```

The image is very small and is not a major problem but I wanted to get rid of it.

- Time Machine is not able to delete it
- I tried to mount the drive and

  - delete it with Finder: the Finder crashes
  - delete it with `rm -rf` from the terminal: `rm` hangs

Any better idea the erase the whole Time Capsule drive? I would rather keep the file than losing all my old spanshots.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? Still a problem with MacOS Sierra in 2017. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshPinter Sadly no. I re-initialized Time Capsule throwing away the old backups.

Comment: Thanks for the lightning quick response, on a Sunday no less! I'm going to try a few things here, including booting up in safe mode and single user mode to see if I can delete it. I'll post back here with any updates that I find. Cheers!